# Using prompt with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, prompt, puppeteer

I am trying to take user input for the username and password fields and use it to populate fields in a web page using puppeteer. My two prompts are not being stored correctly because when I call them in page.keyboard.type(username) it isn't able to fill the fields (I believe its because the input isn't a string and this argument required is a string)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.start();

(async() => {
    var result = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        prompt.get('username', function (err, result) {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
    var result2 = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        prompt.get('password', function (err, result2) {
            resolve(result2);
        });
    });
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const username = String(result);
    const password = String(result2);

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('');
    const BUTTON_SELECTOR1 = '#post-3782 > div > div > p.clear > span > a > img';
    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR1);

    const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#username';
    const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#password';
    const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#col2 > form > div:nth-child(3) > button';

    await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(username);

    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(password);

    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.goto('');

/*
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    */
})();
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking. Have you debugged the issue? Have you tried filling in hardcoded strings (maybe your selectors are wrong) ?

Comment: if it's not inputting username password something's wrong with 
`const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#username';`
`const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#password';`
You got to check if the selector for username and password are #username and #password.

Answer (score 2):

The function `prompt.get()` returns an object (i.e. `{ username: 'johndoe' }`).

Therefore, the following example shows the best way to obtain the username and password for Puppeteer using the [prompt package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt):

```
const credentials = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  prompt.get(['username', 'password'], (error, result) => {
    resolve(result);
  });
});

const username = credentials.username;
const password = credentials.password;

await page.type('#username', username);
await page.type('#password', password);
```